# Azure AzureRmWebAppDeployment step cant find zip file from PublishArtifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I had an application that was on .NET 5 and was hooked up to an Azure DevOps pipeline that built and deployed fine. The relevant parts are:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'mySub'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'myApp'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|5.0'
```

I when I moved to .NET 6 I recreated the project from scratch and ported the code over including the .yaml file, but when the pipeline runs, when it gets to the Deployment step it says it can't find 'D:\a\1\a\s.zip'. When i wildcard it it says more than 1 zip file exists.

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'mySub'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'myApp'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
```

TLDR: How can I determine what the Publish step output as the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be three approaches.

1. Use artifactName while publishing the artifact, that way the artifacts would be published with your desired name.

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

**ArtifactName**: Specify the name of the artifact that you want to create. It can be whatever you want.
Default value: drop

2. Use a bash task to list the content of the directory.

```
- bash: ls $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: "List the content of staging directory"
```

3. Once the artifact is published and your pipeline run is completed, navigate to Summary to explore or download your artifact.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts

[image: Published artifact]

Comment: Went with option #3 and saw the names of everything it produced, and updated my .yaml accordingly. Thanks!